Appium xcuitest driver not able to connect with apple tvos innwifi
I have paired via xcode and my appium inspector connecting but without launching installed app .. however when tried to connedt with python appium client getting 500 with messgae no paired devixe found
Apple tv version 18.0
Apple tv model : 4k
Appium 2
Xcode beta
